# Is there a way to insert a row in a father table with autoincrement primary key and a child table in the same transaction in SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, transactions, commit

I don' t know how to insert a row in the child table that has an attribute that references to the column ID (primary key of the father Table)in the same transaction because i dont know the father primary key if i don't commit the transaction.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you need to commit the transaction to get the referenced primary key?

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your question: you don't have enough data before transaction's commit. Maybe try something like nested transactions? Note that not every database supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has LAST_INSERT_ID() function.

Answer (score 0):

When you have executed your statement, call [getGeneratedKeys()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) to fetch the generated keys:

```
Statement statement =
    connection.prepareStatement("insert into ..",
                                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
statement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
...
```